# Powershell New-SmbMapping with variable

Tags: powershell

I´m planning to connect a network drive via Powershell. The whole script should be highly dynamic, so I want/have to use variable.

Example:

```
$dhcpserver="192.168.0.1"
$dhcpshare="$dhcpserver\share"
$shareletter="X:"
$shareuser="$dhcpserver\user"
$sharepasswd="passwd"

New-SmbMapping -LocalPath $shareletter -RemotePath $shareletter -Username 
$shareuser -Password $sharepasswd -Persistent $true
```

This doesn´t work because of the `-RemotePath` Parameter, if I replace this with `\\192.168.0.1\share` it's ok, but not this way. But why?

Yes, probably it will work via `net use` - that's what I'm going to do next. But the question why remains....

Comment: `"\\$dhcpserver\share"`?

Comment: Do you get an error message? If you do, what is it? Like PetSerAl already hinted, the UNC prefix `\\` is missing.

Comment: I tried already both - with backslash and without. I get the error message **New-Smbmapping : The network name cannot be found**. But if I connect the same drive in a command windows (via net use) its working.

Comment: *edit* The error in the example was a typo.

Comment: I added \\ to the variable *$dhcpshare* and tried          **New-SmbMapping -LocalPath $shareletter -RemotePath $dhcpshare -Username $shareuser -Password $sharepasswd -Persistent $true** doesnt work.    
       But **New-SmbMapping -LocalPath $shareletter -RemotePath \\192.168.0.1\share -Username $shareuser -Password $sharepasswd -Persistent $true** its still working! It seems that the variable $dhcpserver isnt used correctly....

Answer (score 2):

First up, you're using the same variable for LocalPath & RemotePath:

```
-LocalPath $shareletter -RemotePath $shareletter
```

And also your value for `$dhcpshare` isn't a valid [UNC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx) path as it's missing `\\` from infront of the server name/ip.

With both fixed:

```
$dhcpserver="192.168.0.1"
$dhcpshare="\\$dhcpserver\share"
$shareletter="X:"
$shareuser="$dhcpserver\user"
$sharepasswd="passwd"

New-SmbMapping -LocalPath $shareletter -RemotePath $dhcpshare -Username $shareuser -Password $sharepasswd -Persistent $true
```